How to solve recurrence of a two-sided sequence with generating functions?
Given a two-sided sequence
$$...,a_{-2},a_{-1},a_0,a_1,a_2,..$$
with recursion
$$a_n=\frac12(a_{n-2}+a_{n+1}), n\neq0$$
and initial condition
$$a_0=1$$
let
$$G(z)=\sum_n a_n z^n$$
be its generating function.
We have
$$\frac12(z^2+z^{-1})G(z)=G(z)-a_0+\frac12(a_{-2}+a_1)=G(z)+C$$
therefore
$$G(z)=\frac{2C}{z^2+z^{-1}-2}$$

Now, how can we solve for $\{a_n\}$?
If we do
$$G(z)=\frac{2Cz}{z^3-2z+1}=\frac{\alpha}{1-z}+\frac{\beta}{1-z/z_1}+\frac{\gamma}{1-z/z_2}$$
we will lose all the negative terms and $a_n (n\rightarrow\infty)$ will explode as one of the roots $\{z_1,z_2\}$ has a norm less than 1.

Also, another question is that a trivial solution for this recurrence is $a_n=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. How can we derive the non-trivial solution that can be obtained by recursion from the initial condition of $a_n=\delta(n)=\mathbb{I}(n=0)$?

P.S. I am self-studying generating functions and I fail to find useful information about two-sided generating functions online.

I kind of have a suggestion: your solution is a nearly correct.You can think of only nonnegative index and then reversely recuerse to negative index. Then for nonnegative index you can use your argument.

@JetfiRex If we only consider the non-negative terms, we will need to have more initial conditions to kick off the recurrence. How can we do that?

That's the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform (taking this transform gives you a two-sided generating functions - you should really look into that), so taking the inverse $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $G$ gives you $a_{-n}$ (replacing $-n$ with $n$ gives you the solution).

You may define another sequence $b_n := a_{-n}$ in order to treat the subsequence with negative indices separately, hence two one-sided generating functions instead of one two-sided $G(z)$.
However, if you really want to keep a two-sided generating function with negative powers, you can recover its coefficients with the help of the following complex integral :
$$
a_n = \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{G(z)}{z^{n+1}} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2\pi i}
$$
In addition, since you face a third-order linear recurrence, meaning that $a_n = f(a_{n-1},a_{n-2},a_{n-3})$, three initial conditions will be needed, such as $a_{-1}$, $a_0$ and $a_1$ for instance, otherwise you will be left with free parameters.

Thanks, but I found another problem is that the initial condition $a_0=1$ is insufficient to derive the solution I want. How to deal with this problem? (Please see the editted question for explanation of 'insufficient')

@JohnAo, see my own edit.

Define $a_n^{(0)}=\mathbb{I}(n=0)$ and $a_n^{(k+1)}=\frac12(a_{n-2}^{(k)}+a_{n+1}^{(k)})~\text{if}~n\neq0~\text{else}~1$, computer simulation shows that ${a_n^\infty}$ converges to a unique sequence. How can I determine the free parameters needed for this sequence?

@JohnAo    You can't deduce initial conditions; they are given by the context or chosen by yourself. But you may carry the computations with free parameters, by expressing $G(z)$ as a function of two unknown elements, such as $a_1$ and $a_2$ for example. Moreover, you seem to consider a two-indexed sequence $a_{k,n}$, which is a different problem, leading to a bivariate generating function, whose form will depend on more than three initial conditions, but on a whole boundary condition (as done with PDEs in a different context).
